# Install Android-Studio SDK tools

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have a problem with Android Studio SDK Manager like in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcR7B.jpg)
so, I downloaded SDK tools like in picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmxRb.jpg) but I do not know how install it, Please help me!!!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is I don't know how install the new SDK tools

Comment: As far as I know, there is no need to "install" you just put the path in SDK manager and you are good to go... Try creating an app and if it builds I should be fine